# How to clone sharepoint project?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a sharepoint project and it already went on a production. I want to clone that site so I can use if I want to make changes before I touch the production site. is there any way to create a duplicate of my site so I can work offline?

Comment: From your tags I am unable to understand whether you are using SharePoint Online or On-Prem? Whether you have enterprise version or foundation version?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach that using powershell (Backup-SPSite / Restore-SPSite)

Reference [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/backup-and-restore-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/)